# Можно ли в Google sheets перенести исходный формат ячеек с функцией importrange?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть 2 таблицы. Исходная (1) и таблица, куда импортируются данные (2) с помощью функции importrange.

Таблицы отформатированы одинаково. Но при удалении строки в таблице (1) в таблице (2) происходит смещение данных и строки подставляются под формат предыдущей.

Можно ли сразу переносить формат Google sheets с помощью importrange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет при помощи importrange это невозможно.